# DeadLock Issues in Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

Tags: c#, process, deadlock

I [read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) that this portion of code can cause deadlock:

```
 Process p = new Process();

 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
 p.Start();
 p.WaitForExit();
 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Because

> A deadlock condition can result if
>   the parent process calls `p.WaitForExit`
>   before `p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd` and
>   the child process writes enough text
>   to fill the redirected stream. The
>   parent process would wait indefinitely
>   for the child process to exit. The
>   child process would wait indefinitely
>   for the parent to read from the full
>   StandardOutput stream.

But I don't quite why. I mean, in this case here, what's the parent process, and what's the child?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In short this is what may happen:

Application A (your code above) starts child process B and redirects standard output. Then A waits for the B process to exit. While A waits for B to exit, B produces output into the output stream (which A has redirected). This stream has a limited buffer size. If the buffer becomes full, it needs to be emptied in order to B to be able to continue writing into it. Since A is not reading until B has exited, you can end up in a situation where B will wait for the output buffer to be emptied, while A will wait for B to exit. Both are waiting for each other to take action, and you have a deadlock.

You can try the following code to demonstrate the problem:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "cmd";
psi.Arguments = @"/c dir C:\windows /s";
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p = Process.Start(psi);
p.WaitForExit();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

This will (moste likely) produce the situation where the output stream is full so that the child process (in this case `"cmd"`) will wait for it to be cleared, while the code above will wait for `cmd` to finish.

Comment: Thanks for your lucid explanation.

Comment: So ... how can I run a process such as `sqlcmd.exe` with some arguments for not much longer than 5 minutes and read as much of the stdout and stderr as I can capture? I could not find a clean and simple way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The parent process is the one calling `p.Start()`. I guess this is your application (the caller).
The child process is `p` or in other words, the callee.